# Is it a valid Ruby Mash syntax?

Tags: ruby

I find the below mash declared in the readme of https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/haproxy :

```
haproxy 'myhaproxy' do
  config Mash.new(
    :global => {
      :maxconn => node[:haproxy][:global_max_connections],
      :user => node[:haproxy][:user],
      :group => node[:haproxy][:group]
    },
    :defaults => {
      :log => :global,
      :mode => :tcp,
      :retries => 3,
      :timeout => 5
    },
    :frontend => {
      :srvs => {
        :maxconn => node[:haproxy][:frontend_max_connections],
        :bind => "#{node[:haproxy][:incoming_address]}:#{node[:haproxy][:incoming_port]}",
        :default_backend => :backend_servers
      }
    },
    :backend => {
      :backend_servers => {
        :mode => :tcp,
        :server => [
          "an_node 192.168.99.9:9999" => {
            :weight => 1,
            :maxconn => node[:haproxy][:member_max_connections]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  )
end
```

I wanted to know what the below Mash denote:

```
:server => [
          "an_node 192.168.99.9:9999" => {
            :weight => 1,
            :maxconn => node[:haproxy][:member_max_connections]
          }
        ]
```

Is it an array of hash?

Comment: I wanted to know what the below Mash denote: OR Is it an array of hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid ruby syntax and yes, this will produce an array with one element, which is a hash.

```
[
  "an_node 192.168.99.9:9999" => {
    :weight => 1,
    :maxconn => node[:haproxy][:member_max_connections]
  }
] 
# => [{"an_node 192.168.99.9:9999"=>{:weight=>1, :maxconn=>2}}]
```

Mashes are completely irrelevant here, by the way. `Mash.new` accepts a hash. If it's a valid hash, then it will result in a valid mash. Else you will get an error. The code in the question *is* a valid ruby hash.

Comment: Can you please show me the hash representation of the above mash?

Comment: Thank you @sergio-tulentsev